# "At the latter point? Time? Point in time?"

Tags: expressions

If I mention two specific decades (the second one being earlier than the first one), and then want to convey that by the second period of time I mentioned (that is, the earliest one), such thing had not yet appeared, what should I say?

Example:

Mentioning the 1790's

Mentioning the 1750's

1/ "Such thing had not yet appeared at the latter point"?

2/ "Such thing had not yet appeared at the latter time"?

3/ "Such thing had not yet appeared at the latter point in time"?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: "Latter point in time", to me, would seem to convey that you were speaking about the decade which came later, even if you had mentioned the decades earlier in the context.

Comment: Thanks, that is something I feared! So how to refer to the decade I mentioned in second, but which happens to be the earliest decade of the two? Should I just say "at this point," then? I thought this latter option could be a bit unclear too

Comment: I would construct it as - *Alice wrote this book in the 1790's. She was born sometime in the 1750's. However, xyz had not yet appeared by the earlier time.*

Comment: It would be the best if you could specify the decade directly instead of using latter or any other such word.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Two last questions if I may: 1/ "by the earlier time": would "by this earlier time" be correct too? 2/ "specify the decade directly": do you mean "repeat" the decade? That is an option I thought of. Obviously a bit heavier but guarantees the understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If it's that simple, maybe skip 'latter'.

Alice wrote this book in the 1790's.
She was born sometime in the 1750's.
During the 1750's Alice's family discovered a tiny cat in their barn.